# Renaming a result

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to rename a result in MySQL? For example if I have the following table

```
Pizza                     Topping 
--------------------------------
Cheese                    Olives 
Ham                       Tuna
Four cheese               Olives
Cheese                    Tuna
```

How can I do a select pizza so that **cheese** and **four cheese** are returned as the same? For example if i wanted to obtain a count of the different pizzas, I would get

```
Ham = 1
Cheese = 3
```

I want to perform a query such as

```
select pizza, count(*) from pizza_table
group by pizza
```

And the result should be:

```
Pizza                     count(*)
--------------------------------
Cheese                    3
Ham                       1
```

instead of

```
Pizza                     count(*)
--------------------------------
Cheese                    2
Ham                       1
Four cheese               1
```

Comment: Ah, that's much, much better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Use the CASE/WHEN statement in your SELECT to evaluate and modify. [See doc MySQL here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html). And some [practical examples here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Flow-Control/UseCASEWHENstatementinSELECT.htm) to get you started.

This sample really naive but ought to be close:

```
SELECT 
   CASE Pizza
      WHEN 'Cheese' THEN 'Cheese'
      WHEN 'Four Cheese' THEN 'Cheese'
      WHEN 'Extra Cheese' THEN 'Cheese'
      ELSE Pizza
   END AS PizzaType,
   COUNT(*) as PCount
FROM PizzaTable
GROUP BY PizzaType
```

You should modify it to best fit your biz logic, such as using a LIKE statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like `select if (locate("cheese", table.pizza)>0, "cheese", table.pizza) as pizza`? It would be better if you posted actual MySQL code...